# How to make Gradle + Google Sheets API + Java into a single downloadable program?

Tags: java, gradle, google-sheets, google-api, packaging

As of now I have made a chatbot application by combining Java and Google Sheets using the Google API which requires me to use Gradle. So far I have only been able to run the program through Gradle using the terminal.

In my end result I want to be able to send this program to someone and they should be able to install it or run it as easy as possible without having to run it through the terminal.

I suspect that the person might need to download Gradle to run the file since it is needed for the Google API. So I think the best way to do this is to send a zip file (or something else) with the Gradle Installer and the java file and somehow make it install everything automatically. Is this possible?

This is how my build.gradle file looks like

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'SheetsQuickstart'
sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7
version = '1.0'

buildscript {
      repositories {
          jcenter()
      }
      dependencies {
          classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:2.0.1'
      }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0'
    compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.23.0'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-sheets:v4-rev516-1.23.0'
    compile(group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-core', version:'4.3.11.RELEASE') 
}

jar {
    doFirst {
        manifest {
            if (!configurations.compile.isEmpty()) {
                attributes(
                        'Class-Path':configurations.compile.collect{it.toURI().toString()}.join(' '),
                        'Main-Class': 'SheetsQuickstart')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming google sheets api is a dependency within gradle, cant you just build a jar file through gradle build then run the jar as an executable file?

build.gradle file example:

```
  version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
  apply plugin: 'java'
  apply plugin: 'application'
  apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'

  group = 'your.package.path.here'
  version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

  mainClassName = 'your.package.path.here.MainClassName'

  buildscript {
      repositories {
          jcenter()
      }
      dependencies {
          classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:2.0.1'
      }
  }


  dependencies {
      compile(group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-core', version:'4.3.11.RELEASE') 
  }

  repositories {
      mavenCentral()
 }

 jar {
 doFirst {
    manifest {
        if (!configurations.compile.isEmpty()) {
            attributes(
                    'Class-Path':configurations.compile.collect{it.toURI().toString()}.join(' '),
                    'Main-Class': 'your.package.path.here.MainClassName')

        }
    }
}
```

Should be enough for a reg min build file, then add your dependencies.

Comment: I’m not really familiar with how Gradle works, I have just been following Google’s instructions. Right now I run the program with “gradle -q run” in the terminal. 

I ran “grade build” just now and I got a bunch of files in the build folder. One was a jar file which I could not run. It said just “check the console for any error messages” and I didn’t find any.

Comment: Try running "gradle build --stacktrace", you should be able to view any issues. Could be likely the gradle build file is not set up correctly, especially if you can run the project within your workspace with no errors.

Comment: I just ran it. The build was successful as before. The problem is when I actually try to launch the jar file. Do I maybe need a special program to run the jar file? Right now my computer tries to run it on Jar Launcher.

Comment: Well from what I understand you need Java installed on your machine, then you can run the jar file through the command line by accessing the jar location and running, "java -jar your.file.name.jar"

Comment: Great! This worked on my computer! I tried to send that Jar file to my friend but it didn’t work. Are there any requirements for him to be able to open it? Does he need Gradle or any other files?

Comment: To run the Jar all he should need is Java installed, if you want him to modify it then you would have to send him all your project files and ask him to import ask gradle project. Sorry if that isn't what you meant. Was he opening it via command line or by double clicking, usually the culprit. Or it could be a case of installing Java. https://java.com/en/download/

Comment: He tried double clicking it. We tried doing it through the terminal using "java -jar  <filename>.jar" but it didn't work either. Thanks a lot for the quick answers by the way. Really appreciate it! And he does have Java 1.8 installed btw

Comment: Evertything worked on his computer when we built it with gradle on his computer. It just doesn't seem to work when the jar file is independently sent to another computer.

Comment: That seems as if the dependencies aren't packaged properly when building the gradle file into a jar. Such as http://www.baeldung.com/gradle-fat-jar . Essentially you need to package all your dependencies into the builldscript.

Comment: Check my build.gradle file for added buildscript using shadow plugin.

Comment: That tdidn't work either. I edited in my build.gradle file. Maybe you'll find what's wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170792/discussion-between-paul-jay-and-jordan).